# Storing a Minecraft-like map as a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, 3d

I'm writing a map editor that converts a 3D space into JavaScript arrays so that it can be exported to a JSON file.

Each map will have a 2D plane acting as a ground layer (the user will have to specify X and Y size), then to add height, the user can place blocks on top of this 2D plane, following a X & Y grid (similar to *Minecraft*).

My idea was to have an array for each Z layer, and fill it with the information about which blocks are placed there. Because the X and Y sizes of the map must be specified, a simple array should do the trick, as to read the map you would simply loop for each Z layer array and fill the map with its contents, which would be another array. Creating rows defined by the X and Y size of the ground layer.

I know you can fill arrays like `layer[165] = grassBlock`
after you declare them, Which would make everything before index 165 empty and thus save space. But in a JSON format, wouldn't that array have 164 zeroes or nulls before it reaches this index?

Is this even the most efficient way to store a 3D space? I'm trying to minimize map size and speed up load time as much as possible.

Comment: You could you store column like a Map. Values are ordered in Map, hence `let column = new Map(); column.set(165, 'grass')` would mean that everything above is void.

Comment: But how would I store all those Maps into a JSON file? Do I just convert it to an array?

Comment: Yes, here is an example: `json = JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.entries())); map = new Map(JSON.parse(json));`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have block/empty then a single bit is sufficient and you can use a single array Javascript typed array for the matrix.

Assuming size of the matrix is `X`, `Y` and `Z` then the conversion from coordinates `(x, y, z)` to array index could be:

```
index = (x*Y + y)*Z + z;
```

then the map could be stored as a single `Uint8Array` object initialized with length `(X*Y*Z + 7) >> 3` (each of the bytes will give you 8 bits but you need to round up).

To read/write a single bit you can finally use

```
bit = (matrix[index >> 3] >> (index & 7)) & 1;  // Read element
matrix[index >> 3] |= 1 << (index & 7);         // Set element to 1
matrix[index >> 3] &= ~(1 << (index & 7));      // Clear element to 0
```

If instead you need to store a logical ID and there are no more than 256 distinct values (including "empty") then a single byte per element is enough. The `index` computation is as above but you can use as size `X*Y*Z` and then simply read/write element with `matrix[index]`.

If more than 256 but less than 65537 distinct values are needed then a `Uint16Array` can be used.

If most of the elements do not carry specific data except the class (e.g. they're just "air", "land", "water") and only a small percentage require much more then may be a byte map with a value for "other" and then just a dictionary mapping `(x,y,z)` to data only for "other" blocks is a resonable approach (very simple code, still fast access and update).

Note that while Javascript has data types to store binary data efficiently unfortunately JSON doesn't provide a type to send/receive arbitrary bytes (not text) over the network and you'll need to convert to and load from base64 encoding or something similar (if you want to use JSON).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm having difficulty understanding, but to clarify, the matrix won't consist of just block or empty. Rather each block will be an ID which is associated with a predefined object; containing a texture, collision and other properties.

Comment: @InevitableEntropy: added a note about storing an ID. In this case the code is simpler and you can just use `matrix[index]` without the bit-fiddling code.